# "Column name id is ambiguous" error in BigQuery when I'm trying to unnest an array field

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table with schema like this (noly important fields are listed for brevity):

```
id [STRING]
products [RECORD]
products.id [STRING]
```

I'm trying to perform a query and get both id and products.id like this:

```
SELECT 
  id as transaction_id,
  products.id as product_id
FROM 
  `my-project.set.transactions_table`,
  UNNEST(products) as products
```

and get an error: `Column name id is ambiguous at [2:3]`

How do I remove ambiguity here?

Comment: Your source tables must both contain ID.  Add an alias to the selected ID as transaction_ID referencing from what table you want ID to be sourced.   `my-project.set.transactions_table B` and then b.Products

Comment: The issue: `Id as transaction_id` doens't know if you mean the ID from the `products` source or from the `my-project.set.transactions_table`  We assume you want the `my-project.set.transactions_table`  so you just need to alias that table `my-project.set.transactions_table` as B and modify the select to be `B.ID as transaction_Id`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your first id is the ambiguous one. Just need to add the table source

```
SELECT 
  transactions.id as transaction_id,
  products.id as product_id
FROM 
  `my-project.set.transactions_table` as transactions,
  UNNEST(products) as products
```

Comment: alias the `my-project.set.transactions_table` and add it to the id w/o an table in the select  since products and that other table both have Id.

Comment: @xQbert After your comment I see understand the question wrong but I think is ok now.

Comment: Yep, this looks better